# python setup.py sdist only including .py source from top level module

Tags: python, setup.py, sdist

I have a setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
      ...
      packages=['mypackage'],
      test_suite='mypackage.tests',
      ...
    )
```

`python setup.py sdist` creates a file that includes only the source modules from top-level mypackage and not mypackage.tests nor any other submodules.

What am I doing wrong?

Using python 2.7

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the [`find_packages()` function](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages):

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    # ...
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

The function will search for python packages (directories with a `__init__.py` file) and return these as a properly formatted list. It'll start in the same dir as the setup.py script but can be given an explicit starting directory instead, as well as exclusion patterns if you need it to skip some things.

Comment: When I use this function, the `build/lib` never contains modules that are at the project root. If I use `packages=['.']`, running `python setup.py` shows a warning, but it does add modules at the project root into `build/lib`. My project root has both `__init__.py` and `setup.py` and `example-module.py`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: you really should not make your project root a package, why do you have an `__init__.py` there to begin with? Your project root should only contain non-nested modules and packages, not *be* a package.

Comment: Yes, I only realised that later. I thought that project root can be a package as well.

Answer (score 3):

For people using pure distutils instead of setuptools: you have to pass the list of all packages and subpackages (but not all submodules, they are detected) in the packages parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Just include all your submodules in the packages list:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
      ...
      packages=['mypackage', 'mypackage.tests', 'mypackage.submodules'],
      ...
     )
```